# Loops and Storing entered information

Tags: java, loops

So I have to make a bank account program that gets the Balance and for each month entered by the user asking them the deposits and withdrawals for that month and adds or subtracts that from the balance each month.

I got the loop to work but am wondering how I would store the data that I receive, I need to store the deposits and withdrawals separate.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class QueryBankAccount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        String balance = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Balance:");
        String interest = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Interest:");
        String months = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Months:");

        double balancedouble = Double.parseDouble(balance);
        double interestdouble = Double.parseDouble(interest);
        int monthsint = Integer.parseInt(months);

        int counter = 0;

        while (counter < monthsint){
            String Deposits = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Deposits:");
            String Withdrawls = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Withdrawls:");

            double depositsdouble = Double.parseDouble(Deposits);
            double withdrawlsdouble = Double.parseDouble(Withdrawls);

            counter++;
        }
```

Comment: you know what is variable, right? you know how to declare variable? you know how to add one variable to another?

Comment: You probably need an array if you want to store deposits and withdrawals for each month.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store your values in a fixed amount of space use an array, but if you do not know the size and you want it to be resizeable use an arraylist and add your withdrawals and/or deposits to it. For example:

```
double totalDep[] = new double[10]; //assuming total is 10 deposits
  while (counter < monthsint){
        String Deposits = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Deposits:");
        String Withdrawls = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Withdrawls:");

        double depositsdouble = Double.parseDouble(Deposits);
        double withdrawlsdouble = Double.parseDouble(Withdrawls);

        totalDep[counter] = depositsdouble; //store into array here

        counter++;
    }
```

Similarily you can do one for withdrawals as well, Here is an arraylist version:

```
ArrayList<Double> totalDep = new ArrayList<Double>(); 
 while (counter < monthsint){
        String Deposits = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Deposits:");
        String Withdrawls = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame, "Enter your Withdrawls:");

        double depositsdouble = Double.parseDouble(Deposits);
        double withdrawlsdouble = Double.parseDouble(Withdrawls);

        totalDep.add(depositsdouble); 
        counter++;
    }
```